# How can I revive dead pixels on my iPod Touch (second generation)?

Tags: ipod-touch, screen

I've got lines on the top of my iPod Touch (2nd gen) and they won't go away.

I've checked some other forums and they told me to:

- Turn the brightness all the way up and go to some funky strobing website for 6 hours.
- Put it in the freezer (never again)
- Press down on the screen, but the lines are too near the top to do that (without breaking it)

Are there any other old wives tales relevant to fixing dead pixels.  I've seen some come back and go away so I think it's not a totally lost cause.

Comment: If the pixels are dead (black) there isn’t much you can do other than replacing the panel, which is more complicated and probably expensive than replacing the device. If it’s out of warranty, you’re also out of luck. You can try to make it explode :)

Answer (score 3):

I dont know about how comfortable you are with taking electronics apart, but it sounds like the connector for the screen might be coming loose, or the screen might be on the way out. I would recommend buying a replacement screen on eBay, or paying apple to fix it for you.

Comment: I'm fairly comfortable taking electronics apart and fixing them, but replacing the iPod front glass was very challenging. I doubt that Apple would fix this, they may offer a replacement unit for about half price.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a dead pixel (black) or a stuck pixel (stuck on one color)? Those suggestions work occasionally for stuck pixels, but if you have dead pixels, you're out of luck, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of the distinction.  I'm afraid they're dead, although the occasionally seem to come back..  I remember it being a straight line across the screen at one point, now and then there is a little gap.